# Find intersection between collections with different objects

Tags: java, guava, lambdaj

I have list of custom objects like below:

```
List<CustomObject> existingValues
```

And another collection with ids that has been sent from client and contains ids of CustomObject mentoioned above `Set<Long> ids`.

My goal is to return collection with CustomObject that will contains only elements where ids intersect.

I can simply do this with nested for each cycles. But it looks a bit ugly.

In SQL I can do similar stuff with query:

```
select * where customobject.id in (some ids...)
```

In wich way it can be achived with `lamdaj` or `guava`?

Comment: This isn't an answer since you're asking about lamdaj and guava, but really you only need a single loop through the CustomObject List, then using contains to see if the Id is in the Set. Assuming it's a HashSet, those will be constant-time lookups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Guava this is done as follows:

```
    final Set<Long> ids = ...; //initialize correctly

    List<CustomObject> results = FluentIterable.from(existingValues).filter(new Predicate<CustomObject>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(final CustomObject input) {
            return ids.contains(input.getId());
        }
    }).toList();
```

Answer (score 1):

With Java 8 you can achieve this with a stream filter:

```
List<CustomObject> collect = existingValues.stream()
.filter(object -> ids.contains(object.getId()))
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

To get familiar with java streams I recommand the offical [Oracle Tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes as @wuethrich44 says in Java 8 the solution is:

```
List<CustomObject> collect = existingValues.stream()
    .filter(object -> ids.contains(object.getId()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And in the case you have a version older than Java 8:

```
List<CustomObject> collect = new ArrayList<CustomObject>();
for(CustomObject object: existingValues) {
    if(ids.contains(object.getId())) {
        collect.add(object);
    }
}
```

And for version older than Java 5:

```
List<CustomObject> collect = new ArrayList<CustomObject>();
Iterator<CustomObject> iterator = existingValues.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    CustomObject object = iterator.next();
    if(ids.contains(object.getId())) {
        collect.add(object);
    }
}
```

but the version with stream is better: faster in term of execution time, less verbose, and more readable if you are use to it

Comment: It's not always the case that the stream version is "faster in terms of execution time."

Answer (score 0):

If you can use my [xpresso](https://github.com/WantedTechnologies/xpresso) library you can use list comprehensions with lambda expressions like this:

```
list<CustomObject> filtered = x.list(x.<CustomObject>yield().forEach(existingValues).when(x.lambdaP("x : f1(f0(x))",x.invoke("getId"),x.in(ids))));
```